# How Modify a drawn polygon after loading from database in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers

I use [this](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/measure-style.html) example to draw, measure and modify polygon on map. after I draw it, i save polygon vertices coordinates in database. In other page I'm reading this coordinates to add a polygon layer on map using this code:

```
        const polygon = new ol.geom.Polygon([polygonCoords]);
        const polygonFeature = new ol.Feature({
            geometry: polygon,
        });

        polygonLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
            source: new ol.source.Vector({
                features: [polygonFeature]
            }),
            style: function(feature) {
                return styleFunction(feature, showSegments.checked)
            }
        });
        map.addLayer(polygonLayer);
```

Now, How can I modify this polygon and set event listener on modify-end event to store new polygon on database?

Comment: See these two examples: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/draw-and-modify-features.html and https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/draw-and-modify-features.html

Comment: At the `modifyend` event you would write the modified feature(s) into whichever format you wish to store them, for example https://codesandbox.io/s/modify-features-forked-orbfr4?file=/main.js  The format and how you store the result would depend on what you are using as a database, for example https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-esri-edit.html

Comment: Solved. Thank you